# MSSQL Server database owner is a disabled user

Tags: sql-server

I am troubleshooting a slow MS SQL server setup currently, and on entering into the properties of one of the databases (in SQL Server Management Studio -. Database -> Properties -> Files)
I notice that the database "Owner" is set to a domain admin account that is currently disabled.

Is this likely to cause any problems?

Is there any reason I should or shouldn't change it to something else?

[image]

Comment: From what  I see, it shouldn't cause any problems. So, I would say you are safe for now.

Comment: What is a "slow MS SQL server setup"? is slow on queries, slow on starting the service, slow on accepting new connections?

Answer (score 0):

The disabled user shouldn't cause issues but if it's removed from AD sp_helpdb will start throwing an error.
Changing the owner takes some testing to make sure you don't break any applications or processes using the database.

Answer (score -1):

You can change the owner to SA by executing the following command:

exec databasename.dbo.sp_changedbowner 'sa'

Comment: Thanks Jason, but I wasnt asking how to change it, I was asking IF changing it is advisable.